# Safely reading string from Lua stack

Tags: c++, lua

How is it possible to safely read string value from Lua stack? The functions `lua_tostring` and `lua_tolstring` both can raise a Lua error (longjmp / exception of a strange type). Therefore the functions should be called in protected mode using `lua_pcall` probably. But I am not able to find a nice solution how to do that and get the string value from Lua stack to C++. Is it really needed to call `lua_tolstring` in protected mode using `lua_pcall`?

Actually using `lua_pcall` seems bad, because the string I want to read from Lua stack is an error message stored by `lua_pcall`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `lua_type` before `lua_tostring`: If `lua_type` returns `LUA_TSTRING`, then you can safely call `lua_tostring` to get the string and no memory will be allocated.

`lua_tostring` only allocates memory when it needs to convert a number to a string.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that lua_tostring is "nothrow" in case when no conversion from number to string has to be done?

Comment: Thanks, too bad that this information is not in the Lua reference manual.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, When you call lua_pcall failed, it will return an error code. When you call lua_pcall successfully, you will get zero. So, first you should see the returned value by lua_pcall, then use the lua_type to get the type, at last, use the lua_to* functions the get the right value.

```
int iRet = lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);
if (iRet)
{
    const char *pErrorMsg = lua_tostring(L, -1); // error message
    cout<<pErrorMsg<<endl;
    lua_close(L);
    return 0;
}

int iType = lua_type(L, -1);
switch (iType)
{
    //...
    case LUA_TSTRING:
        {
            const char *pValue = lua_tostring(L, -1);
            // ...
        }
}
```

It's all.
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `lua_isstring` function to check if the value can be converted to a string without an error.

Comment: According to Lua reference manual 5.2 `lua_isstring` does not return if it can be converted without error, but if it could be converted. There can still be "not enough memory" or any other undocumented error.

Comment: @JurajBlaho I agree with you. lua_isstring is not safe enough.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how it's done in OpenTibia servers:

```
std::string LuaState::popString()
{
    size_t len;
    const char* cstr = lua_tolstring(state, -1, &len);
    std::string str(cstr, len);
    pop();
    return str;
}
```

Source: https://github.com/opentibia/server/blob/master/src/lua_manager.cpp

Comment: I guess that depends on the context. I'd personally try calling lua_isstring first.